# Can some browsers autoconvert non-ASCII characters in JavaScript identifiers to corresponding ASCII characters?

Tags: javascript, malware, non-ascii-characters

I've been watching some malware attack that recently began to inject a buggy version of a malicious script. They use that script for the last 3 weeks and I began to wonder whether that was really a bug, or they just target a "feature" of some browser's JS engine.

Here are the details:

The malicious script (full version here: http://pastebin.com/zQWepqtz ) generates code that begins with `wÍndow.gloa=(function()....` note the **Í** instead of **i** in *window*. The previous working version of that malicious script generated correct `window.gloa=(function()...` code.

**Question**: Can some browsers "consider" that **wÍndow** is actually the same as **window** and execute that code?

Comment: maybe they define a `wÍndow` variable elsewhere, and are calling `gloa` on it in hope one who reads the code won't notice it is malware and not the normal code?

Comment: No, the http://pastebin.com/zQWepqtz code is the only thing injected. I didn't notice that `wÍndow` is defined anywhere. Moreover, the code won't work in Firefox, where I tested it.